# Mongoose Only Updating Once?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

So I'm making a setnote command so people can keep track of how much they have donated. However, It will only add it when I add them to the database and not after. I don't know why. So it just isn't updating or sending the message that it's even updated.

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const notesModel = require('../models/notesSchema')
module.exports = {
    name: 'setnote',
    aliases: ['sn'],
    description: 'Add a note to a user.',
    async execute(message, args, client, cmd, Discord, notesData) {
        const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please mention someone to add note to.')

    if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('Please state an amount to add to the user.')
        const amountToAdd = args[1]
        if (isNaN(args[1])) return message.channel.send('You have to add a number when setting note.')

        let userData = await notesModel.findOne({
            userID: mentionedMember.id,
            serverID: message.guild.id,
        })

        if (!userData) {
            userData = await notesModel.create({
                userID: mentionedMember.id,
                serverID: message.guild.id,
                notes: 0
            })

            

            const response = await notesModel.findOneAndUpdate({
                serverID: message.guild.id,
                userID: mentionedMember.id
            }, {
                $inc: {
                   notes: +amountToAdd
                }
            })

            userData = await notesModel.findOne({serverID: mentionedMember.guild.id, userID: mentionedMember.id});

            function numberWithCommas(x) {
                return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
              }

              const addedNote = new MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle(`<a:red_check:845104782833352704> Successfully Added Note <a:red_check:845104782833352704>`)
              .setDescription(`${mentionedMember.user.tag} has now donated \`${numberWithCommas(userData.notes)}\``)
              .setColor('GREEN')

              message.channel.send(addedNote)
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to edit exist message or send new one with total donated data?

Comment: @HellCatVN I want to send a new on with the total donated. The thing is, it isn't updating it in the database so it won't send the message.